# AWK search fields recursively?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I have multiple files with names, and numbers:

```
Yolanda 606
Yolanda 669
Yolanda 713
Yoselin 301
Yoselin 312
Yoselin 352
Yuliana 249
Yuliana 251
Yuridia 241
Zaniyah 246
```

I would like to sum the second column for each uniq first column value? So 
Yolanda 606 + 669 + 713 =

```
Yolanda 1988
Yoselin 965
```

I would also like to remove every Yolanda if any Yolanda is <= 200?

edit: I apologize for not being clear, but there are over a million records and hundreds of thousands of names. Yolanda was an example I would like to be able to perform these operations for any given '$1 == string'. two separate awk commands would be better so I can tell what is going on.

Comment: Is this `<=200` rule specific to Yolanda, or does it apply to any name?

Comment: If the rule does apply to any name, does the rule apply before or after the summation?

Comment: Your edit didn't make anything more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would remove the total if any of the values is less than 200

```
$ cat infile
Yolanda 606
Yolanda 669
Yolanda 713
Yoselin 301
Yoselin 312
Yoselin 352
Yuliana 249
Yuliana 251
Yuridia 241
Zaniyah 246
blabla 199
blabla 800

$ awk '{T[$1]+=$2} $2<200{E[$1]} END{for(i in T) if (!(i in E)) print i,T[i]}' infile
Yuridia 241
Yoselin 965
Zaniyah 246
Yolanda 1988
Yuliana 500
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
awk '! ($1 !~ /Yolanda/ && $2 <= 200) { 
        arr[$1] += $2 
     } END { 
        for (i in arr) 
           printf("%s %d\n", i, arr[i]); }' file.txt
```

It produces the following with your sample input:

```
Zaniyah 246
Yuridia 241
Yuliana 500
Yolanda 1988
Yoselin 965
```

If you have `gawk` available, you can use it's `asorti` function to put the names back in alphabetical order:

```
awk '! ($1 !~ /Yolanda/ && $2 <= 200) {
        arr[$1] += $2
     } END {
        n = asorti(arr, sorted)
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
           printf("%s %d\n", sorted[i], arr[sorted[i]]);  }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your data is in **data.txt**:

```
awk '$2>200{sum[$1]+=$2} END {for(name in sum){print name,sum[name]}}' data.txt
```

Comment: This will exclude all values over 200, not just `Yolanda` values over 200.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know if the <=200 rule is applicable to just `Yolanda` or to all names. Right now, I assume all names.

Comment: This is almost what I was looking for I think, I was trying to do it line by line but you just put the data into an array and printed the array. Very cool and instructional. Does it remove all copies of a name if one copy is < 200; or does it just skip adding that record's field?

Comment: The script does not remove anything from the original data file. It simply reads the data file, skip over those <=200, calculate, and output. The original data file is in tact.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
awk '{if($0~/Yolanda/&&$2<=200){next}a[$1]+=$2;}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
Yolanda 199
Yolanda 606
Yolanda 669
Yolanda 713
Yoselin 301
Yoselin 312
Yoselin 352
Yuliana 249
Yuliana 251
Yuridia 241
Zaniyah 246
> awk '{if($0~/Yolanda/&&$2<=200){next}a[$1]+=$2;}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' temp
Yolanda 1988
Yuliana 500
Zaniyah 246
Yuridia 241
Yoselin 965
>
```